# dd-wrt, restart ath0 without rebooting

Tags: router, wifi, openwrt

I have Firmware: DD-WRT v3.0-r33006 std (08/03/17) running on Linksys WRT1900AC V2 Dual Band Smart Wi-Fi Wireless AC Router (2.4 + 5GHz) - (Certified Refurbished)

I have ath0 (5ghz) operating as a client to another access point.
I have ath1 (2ghz) operating as an access point to serve the apartment.

Occasionally ath0 loses "sync,"  as in it either:  1.  disassociates completely from the access point.  2.  it stays associated, but loses it's IP address.

For the most part it is scenario 1 (total disassociation), I have seen scenario 2 just twice (just ip).

--

I'm looking for a way to make ath0 reassociate and re-request the ip, and etc. The whole process.

I have tried (from my memory)

1.

```
ifconfig ath0 down
ifconfig ath0 up
```

2.

```
ifconfig ath0 down
ifconfig ath0 up
iwconfig ath0 essid ACCESSPOINT
```

3.

```
wland
```

--

What is the correct sequence of commands to cause the wifi to reassociate succesfully with the external ap?